# Where to apply the code in How to change color of svg file in Qt

Tags: qt, svg

```
    QFile file(":/logo.svg");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);

    QDomDocument doc("mydocument");
    if(doc.setContent(&file)){
        file.close();
        return;
    }

    QDomElement docElem = doc.documentElement();
    QDomNode n = docElem.firstChild();
    while(!n.isNull()){
        QDomElement e = n.toElement();
        if(!e.isNull()){
            if(e.tagName() == "path" && e.attribute("id") == "path9"){
                e.setAttribute("style", "fill:#904ffe");
                break;
            }
        }
        n = n.nextSibling();
    }

    QSvgWidget* svgWidget = new QSvgWidget;

    svgWidget->load(doc.toByteArray());
    svgWidget->show();
```

[image: 1]

I found a source code on the internet to change the color of svg files in Qt. Applying this source code changes the color of the svg file as above.
project link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsawjrwgoa9h0if/loadsvg.zip?dl=0
When I run the project in this link, the picture is displayed divided into two windows. How can I change it so that a black background picture appears on one main screen? (You must change the IMAGE_FILE_PATH path in mainwindow.h to suit your environment.)

everything......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing two windows in your code, you can embed the svg widget in your mainwindow.

Replace the code instead of yours:

```
svgWidget->load(doc.toByteArray());
//  svgWidget->show();  // 얘가 핵심이네 얘가 빠져있어서 안되었던 것임
setCentralWidget(svgWidget);
```